# How to Multiply two arrays and dynamically plot into HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

new to javascript. I am trying to make a new series in Highcharts using one already graphed series multiplied by another already graphed series. How do I add the new series with its own y-axis? I am using some base code that I have not done myself.

`ChartOptions.Series[index].data` holds an array of arrays: so for example :[1563480488000, 12.144] would be timestamp and datavalue for every data point in the series.

So I would want something like this: 
`[1563480488000, 12.144] * [1563480488000, 1.0] = [1563480488000, 12.144]`

that's 12.144*1.0, and the timestamp is kept.

dynamicChart is a `new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOptions)` its just away from the snippet I am working with.
I've tried the following code.

```
 var voltSeries = chartOptions.series[0].data;
 var ampSeries = chartOptions.series[1].data;
 var wattSeries = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= voltSeries.length; i++){
    var valu = chartOptions.series[1].data[i,1]*chartOptions.series[0].data[i,1];
    wattSeries[i,1] = valu;
    wattSeries[i,0] = valu;

}
  eval('window.console && console.log(voltSeries)');
  eval('window.console && console.log(wattSeries)');
   dynamicChart.addSeries({
       name: 'Watts',
       data: wattSeries 
    });
dynamicChart.redraw();
```

the output of wattSeries is an Array of (2) [NaN, NaN] but It should be the timestamp and the multiplied value.
and It seems like I cannot graph it no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is incorrectly getting values from the array. For nested arrays you should use several parentheses: `array[x][x]`

```
var dynamicChart = Highcharts.chart('container', chartOptions);

var voltSeries = chartOptions.series[0].data,
    ampSeries = chartOptions.series[1].data,
    wattSeries = [],
    valu;

for (var i = 0; i < voltSeries.length; i++) {
    valu = voltSeries[i][1] * ampSeries[i][1];

    wattSeries.push([ampSeries[i][0], valu]);
}

dynamicChart.addSeries({
    name: 'Watts',
    data: wattSeries,
    yAxis: 1
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vpzLou6r/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

Comment: Exactly what I needed. It's important to note that yAxis: 1 is referencing the '1' axis indice specified in the chart options.